# wxWidgets 3.1.0 and Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11)

Tags: c++, macos, wxwidgets

Are there any known issues using wxWidgets 3.1.0 on Mac OS X El Capitan (10.11)? I was able to compile it without issues and my imports are resolving (no build errors) for my sample application, but upon launching I get an instant segmentation fault. I'm trying to run the [minimal sample](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.1/page_samples.html#page_samples_minimal) provided in the documentation. It builds without any errors but when ran, it immediately crashes.

```
Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_BAD_ACCESS (SIGSEGV)
Exception Codes:       KERN_INVALID_ADDRESS at 0x0000000000000001
```

The error shown by the system for thread 0:

```
Thread 0 Crashed:: Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread
0   libstdc++.6.dylib               0x00007fff932ee71a std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> >::assign(std::basic_string<wchar_t, std::char_traits<wchar_t>, std::allocator<wchar_t> > const&) + 26
1   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1.dylib 0x0000000109eee003 wxNonOwnedWindow::Create(wxWindow*, int, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) + 67
2   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1.dylib 0x0000000109ef2321 wxTopLevelWindowMac::Create(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) + 49
3   WxTestApp                       0x0000000109eb7aec wxFrame::wxFrame(wxWindow*, int, wxString const&, wxPoint const&, wxSize const&, long, wxString const&) + 140 (frame.h:35)
4   WxTestApp                       0x0000000109eb7501 MyFrame::MyFrame(wxString const&) + 129 (main.cpp:145)
5   WxTestApp                       0x0000000109eb744d MyFrame::MyFrame(wxString const&) + 29 (main.cpp:180)
6   WxTestApp                       0x0000000109eb7366 MyApp::OnInit() + 102 (main.cpp:127)
7   libwx_osx_cocoau_core-3.1.dylib 0x0000000109ee962e wxApp::CallOnInit() + 158
8   libwx_baseu-3.1.dylib           0x000000010a5d1bf9 wxEntry(int&, wchar_t**) + 121
9   WxTestApp                       0x0000000109eb7216 main + 38 (main.cpp:108)
10  libdyld.dylib                   0x00007fff998c25ad start + 1
```

Line 108 of main.cpp is:

```
wxIMPLEMENT_APP(MyApp);
```

Is this a known issue or is there something that needs to be tweaked from the minimal sample provided in the documentation? I'm wondering if it might have to do with the [System Integrity Protection](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204899) security feature.

Comment: I'm thinking wxWidgets simply no longer works on Mac, as 3.02 fails to build  on 10.11 altogether.

Comment: Not sure if this is completely related with your question but when I upgraded my gcc from 4.8 to 5.1, I had problems with wxWidgets on Windows 10. The program was building correctly but when running it was crashing especially with color selection widget. I have downgraded to 4.8 and everything worked as they should.

Comment: @Dan, are you talking about the minimal sample located at wxWidgets/samples/minimal? The one that comes with the wxWidgets distribution? Also, I wonder what was you configure line to build the library?

Comment: @Igor yes that is the one (I linked to it in my post). I just used ./configure with no parameters

Comment: To clarify, I used ./configure with no parameters to build the wxWidgets lib. I used CMake to build the minimal example and there were no linker/build errors (I used find_package to pull in wx).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

wxWidgets 3.1.0 definitely does work on macOS 10.11, this looks like a build problem because there is just no reason whatsoever for the code to crash in `std::string::assign()`.

You mention that you built the minimal sample using CMake. I don't know how exactly did you do it, as we don't provide CMakefiles for the samples (yet, anyhow), but building it using simple `make -C samples/minimal` in the build directory should definitely work.

BTW, it looks like you built directly in the source directory. This should still work but it's easy to make a mistake (and not easy to find it) if you do it like this, so I *strongly* recommend to build in a separate build directory, e.g. `mkdir -p ~/build/wx-3.1.0 && cd $_ && ~/src/wx/3.1.0/configure && make` (assuming you have your sources in this directory, of course).

Comment: I should clarify, I did not build wxWidgets with CMake, I just used ./configure, make, sudo make install. I built the minimal sample using CMake with the `find_package` module to find wx

Comment: @Dan, you don't have to install the libraries - just use them from the build directory. Also, did you try to just do "cd wxWidgets-3.1/buildMac/samples/minimal && make && open minimal.app". As Vadim said, it is strongly suggested to build the libraries in a separate directory.